# Number regex search in string

Tags: mysql, regex

I stored various numbers in a string in a MySQL database, i.e. "5,15,21".
If I search for the number "5", I want the script to show me that row, but not rows that have 15 in it (when there is no "5" present). That is why I don't want to use `SELECT * FROM table WHERE cell LIKE '%5%'`.
What reg expression can I use to target a specific number.

Comment: If at all possible,  do **not** store multiple values in the same field.  Data normalization exists for a reason.

Comment: are there such kind of values as "`1,5,15`", "`5,10`", "`5`", "`1,12,15`" in the intended field?

Comment: I use it for my DNA research. That field shows which chromosomes I match with another person. So, if I look for matches that I share DNA in chromosome 5 with, I want to show only those. Not people that share DNA in chromosome 15. But sometimes there are larger matches in multiple chromosomes. That's why I store them in one field, seperated by commas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the alternative regex solution:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE cell RLIKE '[[:<:]]5[[:>:]]'
```

`[[:<:]]` & `[[:>:]]` are word boundaries, which means here that the 5 wont be matched unless it's "alone" (not part of another number) no matter it's postion

Comment: Works great, that's the solution I went for. Thank You!

Answer (score 2):

you should use the comma seperator do distinguish between 5 as a 5, and 5 as part of 15:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE concat(',' , cell, ',') LIKE '%,5,%'
```

The `concat()` is used to deal with the cases 5 is the first or last in your list

Comment: Some rows only have a single number, no comma

Comment: @Leveller - it will work for a row such as '5' as well, the concat takes care of it

Answer (score 0):

```
mysql> SELECT FIND_IN_SET('5', '1,5,15'), FIND_IN_SET('5', '15,25');
+----------------------------+---------------------------+
| FIND_IN_SET('5', '1,5,15') | FIND_IN_SET('5', '15,25') |
+----------------------------+---------------------------+
|                          2 |                         0 |
+----------------------------+---------------------------+
```